# What is a meta device?

Tags: lvm, devices

`man pvcreate` says

> pvcreate initializes a PV so that it is recognized as belonging to LVM, and allows the PV to be
>   used in a VG. A PV can be a disk partition, whole disk,**meta device**, or loopback file.

What is a meta device? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LVM parlance, a meta device is a device created from some other device or set of devices. Examples include devices created by the MD layer (`/dev/md1` etc.), representing aggregated devices, and devices created by LVM itself, representing logical volumes (so it is possible to create a PV from an LV...).